# Big Query and R not returning the real number of rows

Tags: r, google-bigquery

I am running this code to connect from r to big query:

```
project <- xxx
sql <- "select *
from test.test"
data <- query_exec(sql, project = project, max_pages = Inf)
```

Now the problem is: if I run the code from big query console I get 189000 rows. If I load the data within R, only 16000. Or if I rerun it 20000. or again 15000. 
Whats the problem here? It seems that R doesn't take the whole set of data but only a (random?) subsample.

```
[1] "x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0"

$arch
[1] "x86_64"

$os
[1] "darwin13.4.0"

$system
[1] "x86_64, darwin13.4.0"

$status
[1] ""

$major
[1] "3"

$minor
[1] "2.2"

$year
[1] "2015"

$month
[1] "08"

$day
[1] "14"

$`svn rev`
[1] "69053"

$language
[1] "R"

$version.string
[1] "R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)"

$nickname
[1] "Fire Safety"
```

Comment: What happens when you turn on the `warn` parameter? Does that provide any useful debugging information? I'm curious if the tabledata.list loop is somehow terminating early, which the warnings should be able to detect.

Comment: Can tell us the project_id:dataset_id.table_id of a table exhibiting this problem? We could look at the table metadata to see if there are any issues with it. Thank you.

Comment: Is it working now? There was a bug that may have affected some users between 11am and 2pm US Pacific Time (UTC-8) on 2015-11-13, which should be resolved now.

Comment: yes, its solved now!